# How to validate dynamic sub list using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, filter

I have an excel file with 2 sheets

In the first one, I have two columns:[image]

In the second, I have an SQL query that loads into Excel that looks something like this:

[image: data table]

I have validation on the first column, limiting the value to column A, so the user can either start typing which item he wants, or use the dropdown to pick.

My issue is that I want to create validation on the second column, so that only the options applicable to that Item are available (ex. if the first column is Item 1, only options A, B, and C are available to be selected.) The SQL data is dynamic (possibly different options in Column B for each A), and new items are added and removed. The solutions I saw (ex. https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/) involved creating the two filters on two axis, but I'm not sure how that would work in my situation.

Comment: You will need to create the lists in helper column then using the process you linked to create the dropdown dependencies.  You cannot go directly from what you have to what you want.

Comment: If you populate the data from your SQL query as shown in the linked tutorial then that approach should work.  If you can only populate your data as shown then you'll need a different approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can create a list of unique values from the first column to use as the source for the first drop-down (e.g. like in ColD below), you can configure the second drop-down to use a "Source" formula like:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(I2,$A:$A,0)-1,0,COUNTIF($A:$A,I2),1)
```

Where I2 here is the corresponding drop-down pointed at ColA values (see example screenshot)
Assuming your source data is sorted on ColA.

[image]

**EDIT**: adding a different (perhaps more flexible) approach:

Define a workbook name like "validation" which points to a VBA function which returns a range:

[image]

Corresponding function in a regular code module:

```vb
Function getOptions() As Range
    Dim m As Long, c As Range, v
    
    Set c = Application.Caller 'getOptions is called from the cell
                               '  where the drop-down is clicked
    v = c.Offset(0, -1).Value 'read cell (e.g.) to left of the one being filled
    'Debug.Print v
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        'do the same thing we did with the DV list Source formula above
        m = Application.Match(v, c.Parent.Columns("A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(m) Then
            'return a range (must be contiguous)
            Set getOptions = c.Parent.Cells(m, "B").Resize( _
                   Application.CountIf(c.Parent.Columns("A"), v), 1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Finally, set up your cell validation list to point to `=validation`

The advantage of this approach (despite being a little more set-up and requiring a macro-enabled workbook) is that the VBA in the function can look at the context of the calling cell (via `Application.Caller`) and decide what range of cells to return to be shown in the drop-down.

Comment: That picture was a lifesaver. Thanks for putting that together. I would have been lost with just the formula.

Comment: Should mention that the formula only works if the data in column A is sorted. +1

Comment: Also, ```OFFSET``` is volatile. The alternative is ```=INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(I2,$A:$A,0)):INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(I2,$A:$A,0)+COUNTIF($A:$A,I2)-1)```

Comment: @CristianBuse - requirement for sorting is in the description.

Comment: @TimWilliams I saw the print screen in the OP's question but I think it doesn't hurt to be explicit

Comment: I agree which is why I wrote "Assuming your source data is sorted on ColA." in my answer.